# How to delay the execution of a callback function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have two functions triggering animations (for `opacity` and `top`) on an element and its child, the second being the callback function of the first.

Between them there is a 5 second pause which I created by inserting `.delay(5000)` *before*  `animate(...)` in the second function.

It works, but I am looking for a way to have that 5-second pause *at the end of the first function* instead.

The reason: I am making the execution of the second function dependent on the value of the `buttonstate` variable (which is set by clicking a button). But the function checks that value *before* the 5 second delay, which is not good, since the function is still executed if the stop button is pressed during these 5 seconds...

```
function fademove_1(slide_nr) {
    $(".slide_inner").css({"top": "70%", "opacity": "0.01"});
    $(".slide_" + slide_nr + " .slide_inner").delay(500).animate({
        top: "50%",
        opacity: 1
    }, 700, fadeout_1);
  }
function fadeout_1(slide_nr) {
    if(buttonstate != "stop"){
        $(".slide_" + slide_nr).delay(5000).animate({
          opacity: 0.01
        }, 2000);
    }
```

I simply can't find a way - everything I tried didn't work. Any suggestions what i could do?

Comment: Have you tried `.delay(5000).promise().then(fadeout_1)`?

Comment: I agree, Promise should solve this problem: @Johannes take a look at docs here https://api.jquery.com/promise/ they contain some pretty good examples

Comment: @PitaJ Okay, I got it - that solved my problem - thank you very much!! (If you want to add that as an answer, I'll accept it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The credit is due to @PitaJ, but here's how I solved it in my particular code. I erased the delay from the second function and appendend it (together with `promise().then.(...)`) to the first function, *after* the animation, as follows:

```
function fademove_1(slide_nr) {
    $(".slide_inner").css({"top": "70%", "opacity": "0.01"});
    $(".slide_" + slide_nr + " .slide_inner").delay(500).animate({
        top: "50%",
        opacity: 1
    }, 700).delay(5000).promise().then(fadeout_1);;
  }
function fadeout_1(slide_nr) {
    if(buttonstate != "stop"){
        $(".slide_" + slide_nr).animate({
          opacity: 0.01
        }, 2000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop the animation and then run it try `.stop(true, true)`.
For example:

```
function fadeout_1(slide_nr) {
    $(".slide_" + slide_nr).stop(true,true).delay(5000).animate({
       opacity: 0.01
    }, 2000);
}`
```

I hope this helps.